# Android Drawing Performance - canvas.drawRect vs Bitmap Drawing

Tags: java, android, performance, drawing, android-canvas

I am writing a particle based game that is mainly built by drawing lots of colored shapes.

**Question 1)**

For most of the enemy units I am drawing 4 layered rectangles by setting the paint and then drawing the rectangle through the canvas.

I was wondering if it is better to draw using bitmaps, or to draw using the canvas drawing tools?  I could easily make a single image of the enemy unit that I wish to draw.

**Question 2)**

For the images that I have to draw to the screen, I was wondering how I need to load them?

Right now I have tons of .png images loaded like this:

`direction1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetMgr.open("direction1.png"));`

I've read that RGB565 is the fasted image type to draw to the screen.  Microsoft Paint has some saving options, but for the most part programs only save as a bitmap, not a type of bitmap.  If I was to start using that new format would I:

1. Make new images and use the same loading code.
2. Use the same images and add something like `Bitmap bmp =
   Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);` to
   convert from the initial loaded format to the RGB565 format.
3. Make new images and change my loading code.

Thanks for any help!  It is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. None. It is always better to use OpenGL and the only downside is
   that it requires more energy from a battery because it's hardware
   accelerated.
2. RGB565 means that image uses 16 bits so that's the
       option you should look for. Don't convert anything, just create them
       in the format you will be using.

Comment: It is too late in the design process to change to OpenGL.  That's why I'm asking.  I need to squeeze out a little bit more performance so I can ship it.

Comment: @NathanTornquist, i guess it very much depends on the size of your images and the amount of canvas methods you would use to draw your guys. How about you implement both, go to DDMS and use profiling using "Start method profiling"/"Stop"? This way you will see the exact % of CPU both occupied.

Answer (score 0):

If the Bitmap aren't moving frame-by-frame, you should try to reduce invalidate() method call. The canvas should only be re-drawn when changes are made and should be updated.